# If I switch two columns in a matrix, why do determinants have opposite signs? (Please correct my algebra!)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Right now, I am studying Leibniz formula for determinants.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants). I have been playing around with properties of determinants and got a result that switching two columns do not flip signs of the determinants (which must happen due to change in orientation). Unfortunately, I can't figure out what's wrong with an argument below.

Let $F: Mat(\mathbb R, n) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be determinant operator. Denote $M = [ C_1, \cdots, C_n]$, where $C_i$ is a column vector. Then, determinant has the following properties:

1. $\det[\alpha C_1, C_2, \cdots, C_n] = \alpha\det(M)$.
2. $\det[C_1, C_1, C_3, \cdots, C_n] = 0$.
3. $\det[C_1 + C_1', C_2, \cdots, C_n] = \det[C_1, \cdots, C_n] + \det[C_1', \cdots, C_n]$.
4. $\det(I^n) = 1$ (included for the sake of completeness, but unused below)

Now, I want to show that switching two columns gives opposite signs. wlog I switch first two columns:
\begin{align*}
  \det[C_1, \cdots, C_n] &= \det[C_1, \cdots, C_n] + 0 \\
  &= \det[C_1, \cdots, C_n] + \det[-(C_1+C_2), -(C_1+C_2), \cdots, C_n] \quad \text{(by 2)}\\
  &= \det[-C_2, -C_1, \cdots, C_n] \quad \text{(by 3)}\\
  &= -\det[C_2, -C_1, \cdots, C_n] \quad \text{(by 1)}\\
  &= (-1)^2\det[C_2, C_1, \cdots, C_n] \quad \text{(by 1)}\\
  &= \det[C_2, C_1, \cdots, C_n]
\end{align*}

What went wrong here?

Comment: Look at property 3. Compare to what you did in the line where you said (by 2).

Comment: The third property says that $\det$ is additive in the first entry when the other entries are fixed. So, the third equality is not true.

Comment: oh ok. Got it. Thanks.

Comment: they do say adding a column to another does not change the determinant; same for subtracting a column from another. The first two columns begin $(C_1, C_2)$  next $(C_1, C_2 + C_1)$ Next $-C_2, C_2 + C_1)$ finally $(-C_2, C_1).$ Switching two columns and negating one of them keeps the same determinant.